# Single SELECT Statement to Retrieve All Possible Combinations of 1 Columns Values Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Say I have a column:

```
COLUMN
Bread
Butter
Toast
Jam
```

I need a single efficient select query that will return:

```
COLUMN
Bread Butter
Bread Toast
Bread Jam
Butter Bread
Butter Toast
Butter Jam
Toast Bread
Toast Butter
Toast Jam
Jam Bread
Jam Butter
Jam Toast
```

Comment: select a.item || ' ' || b.item
  from xxx a, xxx b
  where a.item <> b.item;

Comment: yuck. not yummy...

Comment: "In matters of taste, there can be no disputes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should do what you want, it joins the table on itself and removes the rows matching an item to itself.

```
SELECT 
      T1.COLUMN || ' ' || T2.COLUMN
FROM
      TABLE T1
JOIN
       TABLE T2 ON T2.COLUMN <> T1.COLUMN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c1 || ' ' || c2
from 
( select column as c1 from table ),
( select column as c2 from table )
where c1 <> c2 -- this avoids the commented 'jam jam' :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just a [cross join](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html) with a simple filter?

```
with [Data] as (
         select *
         from (values
             (N'Bread')
           , (N'Butter')
           , (N'Toast')
           , (N'Jam')
         ) as a ([Value])
     )
select a.[Value] + N' ' + b.[Value] as [Value]
from [Data] as a
cross join [Data] as b
where a.[Value] <> b.[Value];
```